# Azure web deployment

Tags: azure, web-deployment

I get the below error when I try to publish my website from VS2017 to Azure. P.S : I already have an Azure account and url created for my website. Error description:

> Web deployment task failed. (Connected to the remote computer
>   ("rdproduct1.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service,
>   but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user
>   name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists, and
>   that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access
>   the site.  Learn more at:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.)

Comment: this clearly states you're using an incorrect username and password so I'd make sure, 100%, that you have the correct credentials.

Comment: I have the same issue ..  i'm sure credentials are correct because i can publbish from Visual Studio ... just not using dotnet publish nor msbuild Publish target.. also tried passing Pasword parameter.. any other thoughts?

Comment: this also doesn't work...  same error: https://greatrexpectations.com/2013/02/02/publish-an-azure-web-site-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 areas that have to be setup to allow this to happen. 
1). Azure portal - Locate the AppSvc Resource you're trying to deploy to. Under the action selection blade, select deployment credentials. Enter a username & pw. It has to be unique and doesn't need to tie to your email or login 2) Within Visual Studio. Right click on the project to deploy and select publish. When the publish page shows up, in the 'Summary' section to the right of the site URL you will see a hyperlink for "Settings" select it. In the page that comes up now, enter your user name and pw in the areas identified. Select Save. Once back on the previous page now hit the "Publish" button. Assuming your build is successful the app should publish with your "authentication" to the app service in Azure.